# use promise series instead async series

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, bluebird, async.js

I use the following async.js code

```
var arr = ['1', '2'];
async.mapSeries(arr, getInfo, (e, res) => {
  console.log(res);
});

function getInfo(name, callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback(null, name + ' from async');
  }, 500);
}
```

Now I want to convert it to bluebird [promise](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.mapseries.html) and I try the following but the delay is not working, I think that probably I need to and the Promise.delay but not sure how to use it...

```
Promise.mapSeries(arr, function(getInfo) {
  return getInfo + ' from promise'
}).then(function(results) {
  console.log(results)
});
```

Comment: Where does the `Promise.mapSeries` come from? Async.js doesn't have Promise class because it relies on the ES6 Promise which doesn't have `mapSeries` either. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.mapseries.html

Comment: To use Bluebird's `Promise.mapSeries()`, you have to change `getInfo()` to return a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for

```
function getInfo(name) {
  return Promise.delay(500, name + ' from async');
}
Promise.mapSeries(arr, getInfo).then(results => {
  console.log(results)
});
```

Alternatively you could have written `Promise.delay(500).then(() => name + ' from async')`.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to promisify your async function `getInfo()` as follows;

```js
function promisify(fun){
  return (data) => new Promise((resolve,reject) => fun(data, (err,res) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(res)));
}

function getInfo(name, callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback(null, name + ' from async');
  }, 500);
}

var getInfoPromise = promisify(getInfo);

getInfoPromise("Mr. Promise").then(val => console.log(val))
```

Comment: Bluebird has its own promisification function, it's better to use that.

Comment: And no need to promisify `setTimeout`. Just use `Promise.delay`!

Comment: @Bergi & @Tomalak Thank you for your kind comments.. However; I am not in the habit of using libraries if the same the functionality is embedded in pure JS. I might be considered as a library agnostic person. Hence there is no `Promise.delay()` or whatsoever in my book. For me this is the proper way of doing the job.

Comment: Sure, but the question is tagged bluebird not es6-promise :-)